# Facebook log-in with app when using Safari or Facebook App not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, facebook-ios-sdk

I've followed [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/) facebook's tutorial on how to authenticate in an iOS app. I've followed each step and the authentication works fine if I'm logged in to facebook in "device settings" > "Facebook", but If I log out from there and try to authenticate using the app or the browser the method sessionStateChanged:state:error never gets called. I also have this method implemented in the appDelegate and it is being called but then nothing else happens:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    openURL:(NSURL *)url
    sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
    annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link is the answer:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/414563691940501?browse=search_506e2a4ecd68e7258709929

In my plist file I have the option

```
Application does not run in background: YES
```

So the sdk fails when trying to start session from the "Facebook App" or from "Safari"

If I find a solution for this, I'll update!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding this to your app delegate?

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [super applicationDidBecomeActive:application];
  [[FBSession activeSession] handleDidBecomeActive];
}
```

From FBSession.h

```
/*!
 @abstract
 A helper method that is used to provide an implementation for
 [UIApplicationDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:] to properly resolve session state for
 the Facebook Login flow, specifically to support app-switch login.
*/
- (void)handleDidBecomeActive;
```